# Не выводиться запись из бд типу Varchar

Tags: php, jquery, phpmyadmin

Не выводиться запись из бд типу Varchar.Отправляю через AJAX запрос в бд, в ответ получаю пустой запрос, но если сделаю выборку и закоментирую некоторое поле, в итоге получаю коректный ответ.

JS:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/loadalcars.php",
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        success: function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log('error');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", 
 "*****","*********","**********","3306");

if (!$link) {
echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
 }
$sql = "SELECT id,mark,model,mile,price,describeru,img1 FROM cars LIMIT 9";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

$res = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $res[] = $row;
}
 echo json_encode($res);
}
?>
```

Если из :

```
$sql = "SELECT id,mark,model,mile,price,describeru,img1 FROM cars LIMIT 9";
```

describeru - если убираю,получаю ответ!

Структура бд:

```
    typemenu    varchar(50)     utf8_general_ci         
    mark    varchar(50)     utf8_general_ci 
    model   varchar(50)     utf8_general_ci     
    year    int(4)            
    mile    int(15)         
    volume  varchar(50)     utf8_general_ci         
    **describeru    varchar(8000)   utf8_general_ci**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте TEXT вместо VARCHAR(8000)